# Is there any test link for Mpeg DASH in both: type = "dynamic" and with multiple representations (bitrates)?

Tags: streaming, mpeg-dash

As title:

I have tried to find some but I found for most of cases 
if the test url is of type = "dynamic" **there is ONLY ONE representation (a  unique bitrate; CANNOT apply bitrate switch)**.

Does anyone know if there is a test link?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are several DASH data sets and test vectors out there, lots of them are listed in [this blog post](https://bitmovin.com/mpeg-dash-hls-examples-sample-streams/). Many don't have live streams, but some have (at least simulated live streams).

The [DASH IF Test Vectors](http://testassets.dashif.org/#testvector/list) might be a good starting point, there are several live streams (look at the column `mpd_type` and search for the value `dynamic`), at least some should have multiple representations.